# FBStreamDialog no longer working as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dialog, fbconnect

I am using an FBStreamDialog to display a custom prompt, capture a text message and then display that message, along with an MP3 file on a chosen Facebook friend's wall. The code has been working fine for the last 6 months in my live app. This week, however, it has stopped working. It can only be the result of a recent change in how Facebook responds to the function calls (I've logged a bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/344519698917066browse=search_4f611f5d302a37460391579).

Has anyone else encountered this problem and is there an alternative I can use without having to recode the entire FB connection stuff?

```
FBStreamDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];

dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Enter your special message:";
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ custom string stuff here"}]}",                       friendName, @" "];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB support response to this says I should just install a later version of the SDK and that they can find no reference to FBStreamDialog!  I think this is poor when app developers have live products.